# Entity Framework Timeout When Executing Table-Valued Function

Tags: entity-framework, user-defined-functions

I have a SQL Server **Table-Value Function**; let's call it `MyTVF` which I imported into my Entity Framework data model. I set its return type to an existing entity, `MyEntity`.

Executing the function directly takes a split-second, but when executing it via EF's `dbContext` it times out with the following message:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Executing the SQL generated by EF to execute the function also takes a split-second.

How do I diagnose what is going wrong here?

Comment: I would set up some monitoring on your SQL Server instance. See if your EF call ever actually hits the database, and what it does. How long does it take for you to get your Exception? If it comes back instantly, I would think it has more to do with the last half of the message: **or the server is not responding**.

Comment: It returns at the end of the timeout period. I'm using azure sql database which does not provide profiling capabilities.

Comment: Try spinning up a local database and see if the same thing happens. If it works against a local database, you might need to get in contact with someone at Microsoft for further help.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - TVF works fine in SQL server but from asp.net core fails almost immediately. Can't believe its timing out but that is the error that is given.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the slowdown in my case was due to EF using stale execution plans.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to see the SQL that is being produced. You can either call ToString() on the IQueryable object query (before calling ToList(), ToArray(), Count(), Single(), SingleOrDefault(), etc) or, better, you can set a value in the Database.Log like:

```
ctx.Database.Log += (s) => Console.Log(s);
```

After that, try running the exact same query directly in the database and see what happens.
In the unlikely case that you need to increase the execution timeout, you can set it as this:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = somevalue;
```

Comment: As I write in my question, the generated sql returns instantly.